# How to fix "Error: Expected expression of type std_ulogic"?

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I'm learning VHDL, I tried to implement "adder_array_generic_tree" with two files, the first file "user_defined_type_pkg.vhd" contain:

```
library IEEE;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

package user_defined_type_pkg is
    type signed_vector is array (natural range<>) of signed;
end package;
```

and the second file "adder_array_generic_tree.vhd" contains:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.math_real.all;
use work.user_defined_type_pkg.all;

entity adder_array_generic_tree is
    generic (
        NUM_INPUTS: natural := 10;
        NUM_BITS: natural := 7);
    port (
        x: in signed_vector(0 to NUM_INPUTS-1)(NUM_BITS-1 downto 0);
        sum: out signed(NUM_BITS + integer(ceil(log2(real(NUM_INPUTS))))-1 downto 0));
end adder_array_generic_tree;

architecture tree_type_generic of adder_array_generic_tree is
    constant LAYERS: natural := integer(ceil(log2(real(NUM_INPUTS))));
    constant PWR_OF_TWO: natural := 2**LAYERS;
    alias EXTRA_BITS: natural is LAYERS;
begin
    process (all)
        variable accum: signed_vector(0 to PWR_OF_TWO-1)(NUM_BITS+EXTRA_BITS-1 downto 0);
    begin
        loop1: for i in 0 to NUM_INPUTS-1 loop
            accum(i) := resize(x(i), NUM_BITS+EXTRA_BITS);
        end loop loop1;
        accum(NUM_INPUTS to PWR_OF_TWO-1) := (others => (others => '0'));
        
        loop2: for j in 1 to LAYERS loop
            loop3: for i in 0 to PWR_OF_TWO/(2**j)-1 loop
                accum(i) := accum(2*i) + accum(2*i+1);
            end loop loop3;
        end loop loop2;
        sum <= accum(0);
    end process;
end tree_type_generic;
```

however, there is a problem in line 26 of the second file:

```
accum(NUM_INPUTS to PWR_OF_TWO-1) := (others => (others => '0'));
```

the Vivado red-underlined on `'0'`, says "Error: Expected expression of type std_ulogic". The file type is VHDL 2008, xa7s6cpga196-2I is adopped.

[image]

Comment: Literal `'0'` takes it's type from context, here `std_ulogic` from subtype `signed`. The expression `(others => (others => '0'))`, an aggregate takes it's type from context - the declaration of the object `accum`, type `signed_vector` an array type with an array element of subtype `signed`. The outer `others` choice is for the range of `accum`, the inner `(others => '0')` for the elements of an array composite of resolved subtype `signed` whose elements have a type of std_ulogic, not made visible by a use clause and found in IEEE package std_logic_1164.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didnt include the package `ieee.std_logic_1164` and hence `std_ulogic` is not visible. The only visible option for `'0'` is `character` or  `bit` from the `std.standard` package, hence the error as `ieee.numeric_std.signed` is an array of `ieee.std_logic_1164.std_logic`.

To fix, simply add the line:

```vhdl
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all
```

at the top of the file.

Comment: Or make the literal declaration visible by selection: `(accum(NUM_INPUTS to PWR_OF_TWO-1) := (others => (others => ieee.std_logic_1164.'0'));`. Note which literal '0' is found by the context of overload resolution.

Comment: Or make the literal of type std_ulogic specifically visible with an alias `alias '0' is ieee.std_logic_1164.'0' [return ieee.std_logic_1164.std_ulogic];`